# I can't retrieve query, parse.com, android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I wanna retrieve ParseUser.
Whn I retrieve ParseObject not ParseUser, it works.
But when I try to retrieve ParseUser object, it doesn't work.
What do I do?

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");
        query.whereEqualTo("username",buddy);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>(){
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> puser, ParseException e){
                if(e == null){  
                    Log.d("User", "Retrieved " + puser.size()+ "!"+buddy);
                    ParseObject pu;
                    TextView genderText = (TextView)      findViewById(R.id.genderText);
                    genderText.setText(pu.getString("sex"));
                }else{
                    Log.d("User", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use User object, you must write "_" front of the word.
not User, _User

Answer (score 0):

Technically the correct way to query a user is:

```
ParseQuery<ParseUsers> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
```